# RxAndroidBle: separate subscribers

Tags: rxandroidble

I'm new to RxJava and RxAndroidBle and would appreciate help with a problem I'm trying to solve. Essentially, I have a BLE device which I subscribe to four characteristics. The data emitted from these observables is combined into one observerable:

```
private RxBleDevice mBleDevice;
private Disposable mConnectionSubscription;

...

mConnectionSubscription = mBleDevice.establishConnection(false)
        .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> Observable.combineLatest(
                rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID0)).flatMap(observable -> observable),
                rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID1)).flatMap(observable -> observable),
                rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID2)).flatMap(observable -> observable),
                rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID3)).flatMap(observable -> observable),
                MyDataClass::new
        ))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doFinally(this::disconnect)
        .subscribe(
                myData -> {
                    this.onNotificationReceived(myData);
                },
                this::onNotificationSetupFailure
        );
```

where:

```
public class MyDataClass<Data0, Data1, Data2, Data3> {
    ...

    public MyDataClass(Data0 data0, Data1 data1, Data2 data2, Data3 data3) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The above works fine. What I am attempting to do is to subscribe to another characteristic. However, this only emits data every now and then. Accordingly, I'd like to connect this additional observable to a separate observer (say `onNotificationReceived2`). I don't want this additional observable data to be related to the `MyDataClass`. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Before your `flatMap()`, insert: 
`.doOnNext( rxBleConnection -> savedConnection = rxBleConnection )`
then use `savedConnection` to set up your other subscription.

Don't forget to null `savedConnection` when you dispose (or lose) the original connection.

Comment: I've tried this but `setCharacteristicNotification()` returns false when I try to setup notifications for my separate characteristic. Meanwhile I've been reading into the issues you've raised and/or commented on rxandroidble Github repository. I'll have a go at using `RxReplayingShare`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution I was after. As per [this issue](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/issues/406) and Robert Lewis's comment, I ended up doing the following:

```
private RxBleDevice mBleDevice;
private Disposable mConnectionSubscription1;
private Disposable mConnectionSubscription2;

...

Observable<RxBleConnection> sharedConnectionObservable = mBleDevice.establishConnection(false)
        .replay(1).refCount();

mConnectionSubscription1 = sharedConnectionObservable
        .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> Observable.combineLatest(
                rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID0)).flatMap(observable -> observable),
                rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID1)).flatMap(observable -> observable),
                rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID2)).flatMap(observable -> observable),
                rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID3)).flatMap(observable -> observable),
                MyDataClass::new
        ))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doFinally(this::disconnect)
        .subscribe(
                myData -> {
                    this.onNotificationReceived(myData);
                },
                this::onNotificationSetupFailure
        );

mConnectionSubscription2 = sharedConnectionObservable
        .flatMap(rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.setupNotification(UUID.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_UUID4)).flatMap(observable -> observable))
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doFinally(this::disconnect)
        .subscribe(
                myData2 -> {
                    this.onNotificationReceived2(myData2);
                },
                this::onNotificationSetupFailure
        );
```